# Is there a drop duplicates option with combine first (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Question:

I currently have a process of taking a file from yesterday, comparing it to today's file, and dropping all values that haven't changed. The idea is to limit the amount of data being uploaded to a database to only data that has changed and is not currently in the DB.

I was recently introduced to the function, combine_first, and I realized that I could quickly get an updated merged file, but I'm not sure if there is a way to also find values that have not changed.

Data:

```
data = {
"inventory number": {
   "1236": "110",
   "5188": "101",
   "19497": "111",
   "5123": "010",
   "27358": "011"
 },
 "cost": {
   "1236": 20.80,
   "5188": 28.86,
   "19497": 112.69,
   "5123": 165.03,
   "27358": 54.02
 },
 "map": {
    "1236": "True",
    "5188": "True",
    "19497": "True",
    "5123": "True",
    "27358": "False"
  },
  "cat": {
    "1236": "CONSUMABLE",
    "5188": "ELECTRONICS",
    "19497": "POWER TOOL",
    "5123": "POWER TOOL",
    "27358": "APPLIANCES"
  }
}

dest = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

data = {
"inventory number": {
"1236": "110",
"5188": "101",
"19497": "111",
"5123": "010",
"27358": "011"
},
"cost": {
"1236": 21.80,
"5188": 33.86,
"19497": 100.69,
"5123": 169.03,
"27358": 49.99
},
"map": {
"1236": "True",
"5188": "True",
"19497": "True",
"5123": "False",
"27358": "False"
},
"cat": {
"1236": "CONSUMABLE",
"5188": "ELECTRONICS",
"19497": "Electronics",
"5123": "POWER TOOL",
"27358": "Home/Kitchen"
}
}

source = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Append and find duplicates solution resulting in desired output:

```
icol = 'inventory number'
combined = source.append(dest)
combined.dropna(axis=0, subset=[icol], inplace=True)
i = combined.groupby(icol).cumcount()
transposed = combined.set_index([icol,i]).unstack(0).T
cleaned = transposed[transposed[0]!=transposed[1]].unstack(0)[0].reset_index()
cleaned.fillna(values=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Desired Output:

```
data = {
"inventory number": {
"0": "010",
"1": "011",
"2": "101",
"3": "110",
"4": "111"
},
"cat": {
"0": np.nan,
"1": "Home\\/Kitchen",
"2": np.nan,
"3": np.nan,
"4": "Electronics"
},
"cost": {
"0": 169.03,
"1": 49.99,
"2": 33.86,
"3": 21.8,
"4": 100.69
},
"map": {
"0": "False",
"1": np.nan,
"2": np.nan,
"3": np.nan,
"4": np.nan
}
}

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Combine First Solution:

```
cf = source.combine_first(dest)

data = {"cat":{"1236":"CONSUMABLE","19497":"Electronics","27358":"Home\\/Kitchen","5123":"POWER TOOL","5188":"ELECTRONICS"},"cost":{"1236":21.8,"19497":100.69,"27358":49.99,"5123":169.03,"5188":33.86},"inventory number":{"1236":"110","19497":"111","27358":"011","5123":"010","5188":"101"},"map":{"1236":"True","19497":"True","27358":"False","5123":"False","5188":"True"}}
combine_first = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Comment: What values/columns are you comparing?

Comment: inventory number is the common key. everything else is up for comparison. any value in any cell that hasn't changed, should be dropped to remove from being uploaded. if for any given inventory number, all associated values haven't changed, that row should be dropped entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `combine_first` anymore, just compare and see what changed.

```
r = source[~(source == dest)]
r['inventory number'] = source['inventory number']

print(r)
                cat    cost inventory number    map
1236            NaN   21.80              110    NaN
19497   Electronics  100.69              111    NaN
27358  Home/Kitchen   49.99              011    NaN
5123            NaN  169.03              010  False
5188            NaN   33.86              101    NaN
```

Comment: And if most of the cells are NaN, further space savings can be had by saving it as a sparse matrix.

Comment: nice! what steps would i need to take to insure r['inventory number'] = source['inventory number'] applies the sku to the correct row? i imagine i just need to make sure my indexes remain constant and both files have the same skus/ are the same size.

Comment: @YaleNewman As long as the index remains consistent across the two, the assignment should work fine.